# Git no ignora archivo

Tags: git, github

estoy intentado ignorar un archivo con github pero por alguna razon no lo ignora, para ello tengo el siguiente archivo gitignore:

```
*.p12
```

lo que deseo es ignorar el archivo "firma.p12" el mismo se encuentra en el siguiente directorio:

```
-Raiz
 -static
  -SRI
    -firma.p12(este deseo ignorar)
```

el archivo debe estar en esa ruta, pero nose como ignorarlo, agradezco cualquier ayuda..!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Para resolver el problema, puedes hacer uso de los `wildcards` tal como lo comenta la sección [Ignoring files](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Recording-Changes-to-the-Repository#_ignoring) de Git.

Tu línea podría quedar así:

```
static/**/*.p12
```

Lo que indica la línea anterior es que ignore todos los archivos con extensión `p12` que se encuentren en el directorio `static` o cualquiera de sus subdirectorios.

Espero que con eso resuelvas el problema.